# I can not use filter after mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot figure out why I can make this to work.

```
datos = data.frame(año = 2001:2005, gedad = c(letters[1:5]))  
datos %>% mutate(año2 = año*1) %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)
```

Error says:

```
 Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'año2' not found
```

Simply because I cannot use filter with a variable transformed in mutate?

Subset works ok:

```
datos %>% mutate(año2 = año*1) %>% subset(año2>=2003)
```

R says:

```
   año gedad año2
3 2003     c 2003
4 2004     d 2004
5 2005     e 2005
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the encoding. If you replace `ñ` by `n`, it all works.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012008/different-results-from-dplyr-filter-starting-with-identical-data?noredirect=1#comment46269410_29012008) that was based on your question also has some more clues. Apparently the issue is reproducible for some but not all setups of R.

Comment: Ok. then should avoid use spanish characters with dplyr. Thanks a lot.