# Different results from dplyr filter starting with identical data

Tags: r, dplyr

When I tried to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009261/i-can-not-use-filter-after-mutate-in-dplyr), I came across some very strange behavior. Below I define the same data twice, once just as a `data.frame` and the second time using `mutate`. I check that the results are identical. Then I try to do the same filtering operation. For the first data set this works, but for the second (identical) data set it fails.  Can anybody figure out why.

It seems that part of the reason for this difference is the use of `ñ`. But I don't understand why that is a problem for the second data set, but not for the first.

```
# define the same data twice
datos1 <- data.frame(año = 2001:2005, gedad = c(letters[1:5]), año2 = 2001:2005)  
datos2 <- data.frame(año = 2001:2005, gedad = c(letters[1:5])) %>% mutate(año2 = año) 
# check that they are identical
identical(datos1, datos2)
# do same operation
datos1 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)
## año gedad año2
## 1 2003     c 2003
## 2 2004     d 2004
## 3 2005     e 2005
datos2 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)
## Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'año2' not found
```

Note: I don't believe that this is a duplicate of the original question because I ask why this difference occurs and the original post asked how to fix it.

EDIT: Since @Khashaa could not reproduce the error, here is my `sessionInfo()` output:

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] dplyr_0.4.1
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.3.1       lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    parallel_3.1.2  Rcpp_0.11.4     tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: I can reproduce the error. Win7, R version 3.1.2, dplyr_0.4.1 Can't provide an answer though.

Comment: I can reproduce this if  I switch to German_Switzerland.1252.  I suspect something inside `mutate` is using a hard-coded codepage when creating the internal name of the new column. The resulting conversion probably converts `ñ` to `?`, the placeholder used when conversion is impossible.

Comment: I can reproduce the error and something weird is happening: if I do `datos22 <- dput(datos2)` I get the same error but if I copy the output of `dput(datos2)` and assign it (paste it) to `datos23` I get the expected result...

Comment: That's it. It's using the *system locale* of the machine, translating `ñ` to some other character. In this case, the character may appear the same but I bet it has a different ASCII value. In my Greek machine, I got `ρ` instead of `ñ` in the error message. I was able to query using `datos2 %>% filter("aρo2" >= 2003)`

Comment: I suspect the machine's codepage is 850 or something like it, which uses different locations for characters with diacritics than Windows 1252 or 437

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is there a way to know how "ñ" is translated inside R ? (when the error message doesn't replace the "ñ")

Comment: I get why they look the same, but have different internal representation. But why does `identical` not catch the difference? And why does `datos2 %>% subset(año2>=2003)` work then?

Comment: You mean `datos1 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)`. It's `datos2 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)` that failed, the one with the mutation. For the same reason `names(datos2)[[1]]==names(datos1)[[1]]` returns TRUE even though I can see the difference: string comparison checks the ASCII codes which haven't really changed. That probably means that `filter` also converts strings but in a different way

Comment: Doing right now - although the morale is dont' use non-english characters until R decides to use Unicode like everybody else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error on my machine which has a Greek system locale by switching R's locale to `German_Switzerland.1252`. I also noticed that both the error and the name of the variable *changed* in the second case to `aρo2`.

It seems that `mutate` uses the system locale when creating the name of the new column, resulting in a conversion if that isn't the same as the locale used by the console. I was able to query `dato2` using the modified column name:

```
library(dplyr)
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","German_Switzerland.1252")
datos1 <- data.frame(año = 2001:2005, gedad = c(letters[1:5]), año2 = 2001:2005)  
datos2 <- data.frame(año = 2001:2005, gedad = c(letters[1:5])) %>% mutate(año2 = año) 

datos1 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)
##   aρo gedad aρo2
## 1 2003     c 2003
## 2 2004     d 2004
## 3 2005     e 2005
datos2 %>% filter(año2 >= 2003)
##  Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'aρo2' not found
datos2 %>% filter("aρo2" >= 2003)
## aρo gedad aρo2
## 1 2001     a 2001
## 2 2002     b 2002
## 3 2003     c 2003
## 4 2004     d 2004
## 5 2005     e 2005
```

The reason `ñ` appeared in both cases in the original question probably means that the machine's system locale is set to 850, a Latin codepage where characters with diacritics have different codes than Windows 1252.

The "interesting" thing is that :

```
names(datos2)[[1]]==names(datos1)[[1]]
## [1] TRUE
```

Because

```
names(datos1)[[1]]
## [1] "aρo"
```

**and**

```
names(datos2)[[1]]
## [1] "aρo"
```

That would mean that R itself makes a mess of conversions and its `filter` that does a proper conversion.

The morale of all this is - don't use non-English characters, or ensure you use the same locale as the machine's (rather fragile).

**UPDATE**

[Semi-official confirmation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067944.html) that R does go through the system locale, because it assumes it actually *is* the locale used by the system. Windows though use UTF-16 throughout and the "System Locale" is actually what the label in the Regional Settings" box says - the locale used for legacy, non-Unicode applications.

If I remember correctly, "System Locale" used to be the locale of the overall system (including the UI language etc) before Windows 2000 and NT. Nowadays you can even have a different UI language per user but the name has stuck.

Comment: One way to figure out that `names(datos1)` and `names(datos2)` differ is to check their encoding. `Encoding(names(datos2))` returns "UTF-8" instead of "unknown"

Comment: Actually, it returns  `"unknown" "unknown" "unknown"` for dato1 and `"unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8" ` for dato2. Yet filtering is possible by passing `aρo2`. Setting the codepage to 65001 would fix this but R doesn't accept all the codepages above 10000.