# R summarize qualitative data based on quantitative subsets (dplyr?)

Tags: r, subset, plyr, dplyr

I am really struggling to figure out how to do a reverse analysis of sorts where I partition data by quantitative values and summarize descriptive stats based on these groups.

To help explain, please see a toy dataframe below that captures my problem.

```
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Color = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow"
), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Both", "Indoor", "Outdoor"), class = "factor"), 
    W1 = c(74.22, 78.59, 45.82, 41.9, 83.44, 97.76, 38.41, 140.68, 
    65.95, 64.46), W2 = c(26.86, 138.8, 41.75, 95.32, 17.57, 
    23.13, 84.81, 93.33, 104.31, 67.66), W3 = c(42.25, 56.37, 
    105.95, 72.64, 82.6, 90.55, 54.55, 122.41, 29.03, 44.09), 
    W4 = c(68.77, 12.67, 58.69, 125.95, 24.33, 34.84, 113.12, 
    10.02, 127.05, 60.3), W5 = c(28.93, 99.35, 126.18, 84.31, 
    138.55, 6.18, 144.63, 99.31, 40.76, 9.42), W6 = c(130.24, 
    149.72, 124.67, 118.97, 102.55, 96.96, 135.88, 38.08, 69.69, 
    120), W7 = c(1.94, 94.22, 12.66, 29.71, 137.53, 116.29, 145.58, 
    40.32, 44.51, 99.16), W8 = c(41.61, 147.42, 40.82, 143.51, 
    114.19, 83.16, 108.72, 86.37, 16.6, 91.13)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Color", "Type", "W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7", "W8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

What I would like to do with this data is loop on the columns that begin with W, which show values for different points in time. Specifically, I'd like to say: For each column, subset based on a value condition like "greater than 100" and THEN summarize the qualitative columns (color and type) based on that subset with stats like the count of each grouping in each week.

So it involves applying a function to each column but then using the specific subset in each of those to return summary stats based on two columns. Broadly speaking, I have used the plyr and dplyr packages in the past to group and summarize numbers by various groups. So in this case, I can figure out how to use numcolwise(mean) on this df to see average value for each color. But I cannot think of how to do this variation.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand 100% what you want. Is this what you want?
Here I filter all the weeks for values beeing bigger than 100 and then get the counts for the combinations of color and type

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, Week, Value, 4:11) %>%
        filter(Value > 100) %>%
        group_by(Color,Week) %>%
        summarise(Count = n()) %>%
        spread(Week, Count)
```

there will be some NA values in the wide-format indicating that for the given week there are no values

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Unfamiliar with that second package so I will take a look. My end goal is to do what you did just for week 8 but for all of the weeks in the df. I do not want to filter by multiple weeks, I want to run the same analysis (the grouping of color and type) for every single week available separately.

Comment: please give me the desired output, how should this look like?

Comment: A similar df layout for each of the qualitative columns. So for Color (not both, just grouping by color) would have all the possible colors in the rows in column 1. Then the summary counts for each week would be in the rest of the columns. So in the example above, the result for Week 8 would be in the final column of the df.

Comment: I edited my answer, if this is not what you want please give an example layout in your original post

Comment: Thank you! What I'm looking for is the wide version of this df. Please share if there is any easy way to do that within the filter/gather sequence you have used. If not, i can just use dcast.

Comment: i just gave you all the steps?? are you missing anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75756/discussion-between-grrgrrbla-and-tony).

Comment: Sorry, can't access chat. Thank you very, very much for your dedicated help. Really appreciate it and your edit above is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: I apologize for another bother, but this function (which worked originally) is somehow now NOT working and returns "Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'Value' not found". Seems like some bug - similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012008/different-results-from-dplyr-filter-starting-with-identical-data - but I don't have any strange characters in my df. Any idea of how to resolve this?