# Problems with German Umlaut in RStudio (Windows 7)

Tags: r, csv, encoding, rstudio

I have problems using Umlauts in Rstudio. First, a .csv file is read in like this:

```
mydat<-read.csv("c:/mydat.csv", 
                   header=F, 
                   sep=";", 
                   na.strings= c("NA",""))
```

When I open the dataframe mydat, it seems like everything went fine:

[image]

But when I use the R-Console, the Umlauts are gone:

```
levels(mydat$V6)
[1] "Ã–fter als FÃ¼nfmal" "Einmal" "Zwei- bis FÃ¼nfmal"
```

I tried using `read.table` and also `encoding="windows-1252"`, but it doesn't change anything. On my Mac everything works fine.

Here is my system. Perhaps there's an easy solution and I'm just dumb, like every other time I posted a question on stackoverflow.

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"

R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.3                         
year           2015                        
month          03                          
day            09                          
svn rev        67962                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
nickname       Smooth Sidewalk
```

Comment: Ah, encoding issues, my "favorite" (not). For unknown reason, the encoding of `View(mydat)` seems to differ from mydat$V6 in RStudio on my PC, too. I used to work around this by explicitly encoding all columns to UTF-8 before calling `View`. What does `Encoding(levels(mydat$V6))` say? What's with `enc2utf8(levels(mydat$V6))` or `enc2native(levels(mydat$V6))`?

Comment: With `Encoding(mydat$V6)` i get
`Error in Encoding(mydat$V6) : a character vector argument expected` The Variable is a factor: `str(mydat$V6)`
`Factor w/ 3 levels "Ã–fter als FÃ¼nfmal",..: 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 ..' And The same error of `Encoding(umfrage$V6)
Error in Encoding(umfrage$V6) : a character vector argument expected` comes, when i use 'enc2utf8(levels(mydat$V6))'

Comment: wrap `as.character` around the factor.

Comment: It´s not pretty, but it seems to work: `mydat$V6<-as.character(mydat$V6)
Encoding(mydat$V6)<- "UTF-8"
mydat$V6<-as.factor(mydat$V6)
levels(mydat$V6)`

Comment: Windows uses Unicode throughout while R assumes that all strings are ASCII encoded using some codepage. Worse, it assumes a 1-1 correspondence between the system locale and a codepage, which breaks down for UTF8. Even that is inconsistent. The console assumed the UTF8 string was encoded in the system's locale (which is only suitable for older non-Unicode programs) while R Studio correctly displayed the Unicode characters.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012008/different-results-from-dplyr-filter-starting-with-identical-data/29013402#29013402) question where inconsistent Unicode and handling actually produced different results for the same German data. You could *probably* ignore the problem if it only affects console display though

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the same locale and same platform and R 3.2.0.

Comment: Just tried with R 3.1.3 and still can't reproduce.

Comment: Mhm... perhaps it has something to do with the data. It´s from a friends´ BA-Thesis. He did an online-survey and exported the data to .csv with that tool. I´m helping him with some plots.

Comment: @Roland the problem is caused when the machine's system locale is different from R's locale, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012008/different-results-from-dplyr-filter-starting-with-identical-data/29013402#29013402) similar case.

Comment: @SEMson you may be able to overcome the problem by ensuring the user's, machine's and R's locale are the same. Try all German first, then all US English. This should bypass any inconsistencies. Note that changing the system locale requires a reboot.

Comment: There´s another workaround. I could use a function like this: `umlaute <- function(variable) {                                                                                    
                           variable <- gsub("Ã¼","ü",variable)                            
                           variable <- gsub("ÃŸ","ß",variable)
                           variable <- gsub("Ã¶r","ö",variable)
                           variable <- gsub("Ã¤","ä",variable)
                    return(variable)
                    }`